# Custom imageview with background and src

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-custom-view

I've been using [CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) till now. But now I need to add background as well as src. Both these features are available in native ImageView. But when I add background color to CircleImageView, the background becomes square instead of circle. I tried many custom circle imageview but to no avail. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: whats the point of the round background if it will be covered by round src?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Point is the background will have a color code and the src will have a drawable image which is png. So the png icon will have a colored background @pskink

Comment: I have posted my answer. No need to use CricleImageView. Using glide we can create a circle.

Answer (score 1):

Use this RoundedImageView code from github

[RoundedImageView](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView)

Comment: This library has both features and its working well. Thanks @Rudresh

Answer (score 0):

**Check my code using glide with normal imageview:**

```
Glide.with(getActivity()).load(dashBoardCompanyInfoModel.getLogo()).asBitmap().into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(ivProfile) {
                                @Override
                                protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                                  final RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable =
                                           RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), resource);
                                    circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
                                    ivProfile.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
                                }
                            });
```